# unable to remove partially installed packages

Tags: package-management

```
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
[sudo] password for naushad:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 12.3 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 207666 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 (2) ...
sed: can't read usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 (--remove):
 installed oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632 package post-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$
```

I have also tried these codes but doesn't work.

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get clean    
sudo apt-get autoremove    
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade    
sudo dpkg --configure -a    
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Try and re-install it again so that file exist, then remove it...

Comment: which code i use for re-install

Comment: Please run `apt search oem-touchpad*` and post the results...

Comment: naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$ apt search oem-touchpad
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
oem-touchpad-synaptics-enable-right-button-1584632/now 2 all [installed,local]
  Enable synaptics Clickpad in Xorg.conf

naushad@naushad-Inspiron-14-3467:~$

Comment: actually sir wifi and bluetooth is not working. in wifi setting written as make sure you have a wifi adapter plugged and turned on. some days before its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You original problem may be fixed with simple trick - you can create the needed file manually:

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
sudo touch /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-synaptics.conf
```

and then use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```